# Why doesn't a mono service restart after a kill -9?

Tags: mono, mono-service

I ran a mono-service with

```
mono-service2 -l:lockfile process.exe
```

It started the service and it was all fine but I had to change something in source. So I recompiled and deployed it. I killed the service by running

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Now I tried to run the service again. But it doesn't start at all. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When mono starts a service, it creates a lock in /tmp based on the program name or given parameter. You should stop the service by sending the SIGTERM not SIGKILL signal - if you did so, the lock would be deleted. Now you should manually delete the lock. Read details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono-service).

Comment: @King Tell us more details. Was the pid in lock file? Did the program start after you have removed the lock file? (Cause the former problem was that the program does not start).

Comment: It started after removing the lock file. But isn't it supposed to work when you kill it by SIGTERM. It dint shutdown the service. Killing by SIGKILL and then deleting the file and then starting the service looks meaningless. Deploying such applications, how can one do this flawlessly rather deleting a file and starting again.

Comment: So the first issue is resolved. On the second one - maybe the problem is in the OnStop() method of service, which does not end for some reason. Or maybe the service spawns some non-background threads?

Comment: shouldn't the pid file contain a pid which could be validated by mono-service instead of outright failure? Fx. if a breaker trips this means we need to staff a human being to correct a bunch of machines, or implement logon/init scripts to destroy any lingering lock files. phooey!